# jQuery on click the box should stay open?

Tags: jquery

It is not simple to explain... this is my HTML & jQuery code:

**HTML :**

```
<div class="button">
    search
    <div class="hiddencontent"><input type="search" name="search" /> </div>
</div>

<div class="button">
    phone
    <div class="hiddencontent">9464564654564</div>
</div>

<div class="button">
    mail
    <div class="hiddencontent">example@example.com</div>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT :**

```
$('.button').on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).find('.hiddencontent').fadeOut();
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $('.hiddencontent').fadeOut();
        $(this).addClass('active').fadeIn();
        $(this).find('.hiddencontent').fadeIn();
    }
});
```

**[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pgt488af/)**

By the first button "search" I have a input box, on other boxes is the effect ok. but when I click inside this input box the box going closed, what have I to do to keep it open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   $('input[type=search]').on('click', function () {
       return false;
   });
```

to prevent it from getting hidden [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/pgt488af/3/)

Answer (score 2):

That is because input text lies in parent `.button` which has event attached to it. Due to which, event is propagated to child elements as well. you can check the target of handler before executing other code.Like this:

```
$('.button').on('click', function (e) {
 if($(e.target).is('.button')){
  //rest code
 }
});
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wkf6n28t/)**

Answer (score 0):

Add this code:

```
$('.hiddencontent').on('click',function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/pgt488af/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.button').on('click', function (e) {
    if($(e.target).is('.button')){
       if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                $(this).find('.hiddencontent').fadeOut();
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            } else {
                $('.hiddencontent').fadeOut();
                $(this).addClass('active').fadeIn();
                $(this).find('.hiddencontent').fadeIn();
            }
     }

});
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/pgt488af/2/)